# Why does Nokogiri strip the content?

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri

I have this content:

```
<div class="CodeRay">
  <div class="code"><pre>puts <span style="background-color:#fff0f0;color:#D20"><span style="color:#710">&quot;</span><span style="">Hello, world!</span><span style="color:#710">&quot;</span></span></pre></div>
</div>
```

and I want to add it to a HTML document using Nokogiri:

```
File.open("frame2.html", "r") do |file|
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(file)
end
doc.at_css("body") = content # this is my content 
puts doc.to_html
```

Then content transformed to this:

```
&lt;div class="CodeRay"&gt;
  &lt;div class="code"&gt;&lt;pre&gt;puts &lt;span style="background-color:#fff0f0;color:#D20"&gt;&lt;span style="color:#710"&gt;&amp;quot;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;span style=""&gt;Hello, world!&lt;/span&gt;&lt;span style="color:#710"&gt;&amp;quot;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/pre&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
```

Another part of HTML file is OK. The question is why does Nokogiri strip the content? Why does it tranform it to HTML entities?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I reformatted your inner HTML to make it a bit more readable as a sample.

Nokogiri isn't stripping anything, it's only encoding the content being added because you're telling it to.

Unless you tell Nokogiri the new text is already HTML it will assume you are adding text, and, since the text contains characters that should be encoded, it encodes it for you.

Here's how to do what you really want:

```
require "nokogiri"

html = '<div class="CodeRay">
  <div class="code">
    <pre>puts <span style="background-color:#fff0f0;color:#D20">
      <span style="color:#710">&quot;</span>
      <span style="">Hello, world!</span>
      <span style="color:#710">&quot;</span>
      </span>
    </pre>
  </div>
</div>'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML('<html><body></body></html>')
doc.at('body').inner_html = html
puts doc.to_html

>> <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
>> <html><body><div class="CodeRay">
>>   <div class="code">
>>     <pre>puts <span style="background-color:#fff0f0;color:#D20">
>>       <span style="color:#710">"</span>
>>       <span style="">Hello, world!</span>
>>       <span style="color:#710">"</span>
>>       </span>
>>     </pre>
>>   </div>
>> </div></body></html>
```